# Is there a dictionary of standard character variants?

Tags: traditional-vs-simplified, characters, topolect

Is there a (paper or online) dictionary/list that contains **standard** variants of Chinese characters next to each other? That is, the Kangxi Dictionary forms (正字／康熙字典體), the forms recommended in mainland China, Taiwan, Hong Kong, etc. It would be great if it also showed the characters in different fonts (宋體／明體、黑體、楷書、行書、草書、隸書、⋯⋯), but I'm afraid it may be too much to ask. I know about the [Dictionary of Chinese Character Variants](http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/eng.htm), but it doesn't seem to contain that information.

For example, I'm looking for a dictionary that would illustrate differences between Hong Kong and Taiwan, such as in this picture (Hong Kong on the top, Taiwan on the bottom, source: [CLIAC](http://www.ogcio.gov.hk/en/business/tech_promotion/ccli/cliac/glyphs_guidelines.htm)):

[image: Differences between Hong Kong and Taiwan glyphs]

Or something like this:

> From right to left: Kangxi Dictionary forms, Mainland China standard, Hong Kong standard, Taiwan standard, Japanese standard. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_Chinese_character#Orthodox_and_vulgar_variants))

[image: Standard Character Variants. Source: Wikimedia Commons]

Or like this (click to enlarge):

(Song/Ming fonts)
[image: PRC, HK, TW, Kangxi differences, Song/Ming fonts]

(Regular script)
[image: PRC/TW differences, regular script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[中文]
http://www.zdic.net/z/18/zy/5B87.htm

[EN]
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AE%87

other useful dictionary

```
http://chinese-linguipedia.org/clk/search/%E5%AE%87/86588/182973?srchType=1
http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%AE%87
http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra01006.htm
http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?characterInput=%E5%AE%87
```

Comment: ZDic looks like a great resource, thank you!